# transpose time to columns from date time rows

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have a following data table.

| Timestamp | Energy_KWh |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 00:30:00 | 11 |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 9 |
| 2021-01-01 01:30:00 | 8 |
| 2021-01-01 02:00:00 | 9 |
| 2021-01-01 02:30:00 | 13 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 16 |
| 2021-01-02 00:30:00 | 19 |
| 2021-01-02 01:00:00 | 90 |
| 2021-01-02 01:30:00 | 81 |
| 2021-01-02 02:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 02:30:00 | 11 |

I want to change time part into columns.. like this..

| DATE | 00:00:00 | 00:30:00 | 01:00:00 | 01:30:00 | 02:00:00 | 02:30:00 | 03:00:00 | 03:30:00... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 10 | 11 | 9 | 8 |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-01-02 | 16 | 19 | 90 | 81 |  |  |  |  |

The time goes on for all day.. there should be 48 columns (24 hours x 2)

I would be thankful if anyone can help with this issue.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may split the 'Timestamp' at the space (with `separate`), create two columns ('Date', 'Time') and use `pivot_wider` for reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   separate(Timestamp, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep="\\s+") %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Time, values_from = Energy_KWh)
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  Date       `00:00:00` `00:30:00` `01:00:00` `01:30:00` `02:00:00` `02:30:00`
  <chr>           <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1 2021-01-01         10         11          9          8          9         13
2 2021-01-02         16         19         90         81          1         11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("2021-01-01 00:00:00", "2021-01-01 00:30:00", 
"2021-01-01 01:00:00", "2021-01-01 01:30:00", "2021-01-01 02:00:00", 
"2021-01-01 02:30:00", "2021-01-02 00:00:00", "2021-01-02 00:30:00", 
"2021-01-02 01:00:00", "2021-01-02 01:30:00", "2021-01-02 02:00:00", 
"2021-01-02 02:30:00"), Energy_KWh = c(10L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 
13L, 16L, 19L, 90L, 81L, 1L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: This platform is great.... Full of awesome people..

Comment: I just accepted bro... Thank you so much.. May I ask you one question? Where did you learn R from?

Comment: @prp Just by spending time answering questions.  SO is a great platform to learn if you know how to use it.  The social interaction involves in Q&A greatly enhances learning process

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach, allthough I would prefer akrun's approach!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)
df %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp)) %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(Timestamp),
         time = as_hms(Timestamp), .keep="unused"
         ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = Energy_KWh)
```

```
date       `00:00:00` `00:30:00` `01:00:00` `01:30:00` `02:00:00` `02:30:00`
  <date>          <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1 2021-01-01         10         11          9          8          9         13
2 2021-01-02         16         19         90         81          1         11
>
```